# PyCharm: long waiting for console/debugging

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm 4, and noticed that after working some time with the project, the Run and Debugging takes a long time to establish the console connection. In contrast, if I run the same code using Python console (also in PyCharm) with `runfile('file_path.py')` it starts immediately, and Python console does not take long time to start. Similarly, if I start a new project, and add the old files there, PyCharm Run and Debugging connects to the console much faster. Did anybody face this issue as well?

Comment: Re-install your PyCharm?

Comment: @m170897017: how would that help if everything works fine for the new projects? I'd expect it has to deal with cleaning the cache or something of that kind.